# Switching Gouraud and Phong Shading

Tags: html, webgl, light, shading

I'm writing an application where I need to switch these two shading techniques.

The program starts applying the Gouraud shading , and there are no problem.

When I click the button to switch the shading my object (a rotating cube) became all violet , like there is no light. Does anyone see the problem ?

[image: Gouraud Shading]
[image: Phong Shading]

Here is the code :

**JavaScript**

```
"use strict";

var canvas;
var gl;

var numVertices  = 36;

var numChecks = 8;

var program;
var program2;

var c;

var flag = true;

var direction = true;

var rx;
var ry;
var rz;
var traslation_loc;
var tx = 0 ;
var ty = 0;
var tz = 0;
var scaling_loc;
var sx = 1.0;
var sy = 1.0;
var sz = 1.0;

var pointsArray = [];
var colorsArray = [];





//Point 4
// cambia eventualmente near e far per vedere gli effetti
var near = 0.3;
var far = 3.0;


var phi    = 0.0;
var radius = 1.5;
var left = -1.0;
var right = 1.0;
var ytop = 1.0;
var bottom = -1.0;

var mvMatrix, pMatrix;
var modelView, projection;
var eye;

const at = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
const up = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

//var eye = vec3(1, 1, 1);
//var eye = vec3(0.02, 0.02, 0.02);
//

//Point 5
var fovy = 45.0;
var aspect;
var orthoBool = true;
var aspect = 1.0;
//


//Poinit 6
var lightAmbient = vec4(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0);
var lightDiffuse = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
var lightSpecular = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
var lightPosition = vec4(0.3, 0.2, 0.8,0.0);



var materialAmbient = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
var materialDiffuse = vec4(1.0, 0.8, 0.0, 1.0);
var materialSpecular = vec4(1.0, 0.8, 0.0, 1.0);
var materialShininess = 100.0;

var normalsArray = [];

// Point 7
var changeShading = true;



//


var vertices = [
    vec4( -0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( 0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( 0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( 0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( 0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0 )
];




/* rimossi per il punto 6
var vertexColors = [
    vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // black
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // yellow
    vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // green
    vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // blue
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // magenta
    vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // white
    vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 )   // cyan
];
*/
var xAxis = 0;
var yAxis = 1;
var zAxis = 2;
var axis = xAxis;

var theta = [45.0, 45.0, 45.0];


//var thetaLoc;






function quad(a, b, c, d) {

    // Point 6
    var t1 = subtract(vertices[b], vertices[a]);
    var t2 = subtract(vertices[c], vertices[b]);
    var normal = cross(t1, t2);
    var normal = vec3(normal);
    // *****

    //*** Abbiamo rimpizzato i colori on queli del materiale per svolgere il punto 6

     pointsArray.push(vertices[a]);
     //colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     normalsArray.push(normal);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[b]);
     //colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     normalsArray.push(normal);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[c]);
     //colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     normalsArray.push(normal);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[a]);
     //colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     normalsArray.push(normal);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[c]);
     //colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     normalsArray.push(normal);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[d]);
     //colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     normalsArray.push(normal);
}

function colorCube()
{
    quad( 1, 0, 3, 2 );
    quad( 2, 3, 7, 6 );
    quad( 3, 0, 4, 7 );
    quad( 6, 5, 1, 2 );
    quad( 4, 5, 6, 7 );
    quad( 5, 4, 0, 1 );
}


window.onload = function init() {

    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );

    // Point 5 -> define aspect
    aspect = canvas.width/canvas.height;

    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    //
    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    //


    program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );


    gl.useProgram(program);

    colorCube();


    //Point 6

    var nBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, nBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(normalsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vNormal = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vNormal" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vNormal, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vNormal );


    //*************
    // RIMPIAZZATI I COLORI PER IL PUNTO 6
    //var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    //gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer );
    //gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colorsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    //var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
    //gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    //gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor );

    var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(pointsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    // Possiamo commentare quello che riguarda il theta per il punto 2
    //thetaLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "theta");

    // Point 2 - Rotation

    //X AXIS

    rx = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "rx");


    //Y AXIS

    ry = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "ry");



    //Z AXIS

     rz = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "rz");


    // Traslation Matrix

    traslation_loc = gl.getUniformLocation(program , "traslation");

    // Scaling Matrix

    scaling_loc = gl.getUniformLocation(program , "scaling");

    // Projection and Model matrix
    modelView = gl.getUniformLocation( program, "modelView" );
    projection = gl.getUniformLocation( program, "projection" );


    //**************


 document.getElementById("ButtonX").onclick = function(){axis = xAxis;};
 document.getElementById("ButtonY").onclick = function(){axis = yAxis;};
 document.getElementById("ButtonZ").onclick = function(){axis = zAxis;};
 document.getElementById("ButtonT").onclick = function(){flag = !flag;};
 document.getElementById("Direction").onclick = function() { direction = !direction;};
 document.getElementById( "slideX" ).oninput = function(){ tx = parseFloat(event.target.value,10); };
 document.getElementById( "slideY" ).oninput = function(){ ty = parseFloat(event.target.value,10); };
 document.getElementById( "slideZ" ).oninput = function(){ tz = parseFloat(event.target.value,10); };
 document.getElementById( "ScalingX" ).oninput = function(){ sx = parseFloat(event.target.value,10); };
 document.getElementById( "ScalingY" ).oninput = function(){ sy = parseFloat(event.target.value,10); };
 document.getElementById( "ScalingZ" ).oninput = function(){ sz = parseFloat(event.target.value,10); };

 // Point 5
 document.getElementById("OrthoPersp").onclick = function(){orthoBool = !orthoBool;};

 // Point 4

    // per documentazine leggi la parte sotto il codice a pag 244 con spiegazione sul clip out
    // cambiato inserito due sliders // perspective -> ortho -> + lontano


    document.getElementById("zFarSlider").onchange = function() {
        far = event.srcElement.value;
    };

    document.getElementById("zNearSlider").onchange = function() {
        near = event.srcElement.value;
    };

    // POINT 7

    document.getElementById("ShadingButton").onclick = function(){changeShading = !changeShading;};

    //Point 6

    var ambientProduct = mult(lightAmbient, materialAmbient);
    var diffuseProduct = mult(lightDiffuse, materialDiffuse);
    var specularProduct = mult(lightSpecular, materialSpecular);

    gl.uniform4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(program, "ambientProduct"),
                  flatten(ambientProduct));
    gl.uniform4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(program, "diffuseProduct"),
                  flatten(diffuseProduct) );
    gl.uniform4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(program, "specularProduct"),
                  flatten(specularProduct) );
    gl.uniform4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(program, "lightPosition"),
                  flatten(lightPosition) );
    gl.uniform1f(gl.getUniformLocation(program, "shininess"),materialShininess);

    //*************************************









    render();
}








var render = function() {
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    // Point 4
    //*************************************
    //eye = vec3(radius*Math.sin(phi), radius*Math.sin(theta),
              // radius*Math.cos(phi)); RIMANE COMMENTATO

    //mvMatrix = lookAt(eye, at , up);
    //pMatrix = ortho(left, right, bottom, ytop, near, far);

    //gl.uniformMatrix4fv( modelView, false, flatten(mvMatrix) );
    //gl.uniformMatrix4fv( projection, false, flatten(pMatrix) );


    //*************************************


    //Point 7
    gl.uniform1f(gl.getUniformLocation(program, "changeShading"),changeShading);





    // Point 3 -> Scaling

    var scaling = [sx , 0.0 , 0.0 , 0.0,
                   0.0  , sy, 0.0 , 0.0,
                   0.0 , 0.0 , sz , 0.0,
                   0.0 , 0.0 , 0.0 , 1];
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(scaling_loc,false,scaling);


    // ****************************************
    //X AXIS - Point 2
    var theta_x_degree  = theta[0];
    var theta_x_radians = theta_x_degree * Math.PI / 180;
    var s_x = Math.sin(theta_x_radians);
    var c_x = Math.cos(theta_x_radians);
    var rx_loc = [ 1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,
                  0.0,  c_x,  s_x, 0.0,
                  0.0, -s_x,  c_x, 0.0,
                  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0 ];
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(rx, false, rx_loc);

    //Y AXIS - Point 2
    var theta_y_degree  = theta[1];
    var theta_y_radians = theta_y_degree * Math.PI / 180;
    var s_y = Math.sin(theta_y_radians);
    var c_y = Math.cos(theta_y_radians);
    var ry_loc = [ c_y, 0.0, -s_y, 0.0,
                  0.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0,
                  s_y, 0.0,  c_y, 0.0,
                  0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0 ];
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(ry, false, ry_loc);


    //Z AXIS - Point 2
    var theta_z_degree  = theta[2];
    var theta_z_radians = theta_z_degree * Math.PI / 180;
    var s_z = Math.sin(theta_z_radians);
    var c_z = Math.cos(theta_z_radians);
    var rz_loc = [ c_z, s_z, 0.0, 0.0,
                  -s_z,  c_z, 0.0, 0.0,
                  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
                  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0  ];
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(rz, false, rz_loc);

    // ****************************************

    // Point 3 -> Traslation

    var traslation = [1.0 , 0.0 , 0.0 , 0.0,
                      0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0 , 0.0,
                      0.0 , 0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0,
                       tx , ty , tz , 1.0];

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(traslation_loc,false,traslation);


    // ****************************************

    //Point 4-5
    //*************************************
    //eye = vec3(0.02, 0.02, 0.02); // se lasciassi questo , non mi si sposterebbero le normali per la luce
    eye = vec3(radius*Math.sin(theta_x_radians)*Math.cos(phi),
               radius*Math.sin(theta_y_radians)*Math.sin(phi), radius*Math.cos(theta_z_radians));

    mvMatrix = lookAt(eye, at , up);

    if (orthoBool) {
        pMatrix = ortho(left, right, bottom, ytop, near, far); }
    else {
        pMatrix=perspective(fovy , aspect , near , far); }

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv( modelView, false, flatten(mvMatrix) );
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv( projection, false, flatten(pMatrix) );


    //*************************************


    // ****************************************

    // Point 1 --> Change and Toggle Rotation
    if((direction)&&(!flag)) theta[axis] += -1.0;
    if((!direction)&&(!flag)) theta[axis] += +1.0;

    if(!direction) {theta[axis] += -1.0; }
    if(direction) {theta[axis] += 1.0 ; }

    // ****************************************

    //gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, theta);
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices );
    requestAnimFrame(render);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <button id = "ButtonX">Rotate X</button>
    <button id = "ButtonY">Rotate Y</button>
    <button id = "ButtonZ">Rotate Z</button>
    <button id = "ButtonT">Toggle Rotation</button>
    <button id="Direction">Change Direction</button>
    <button id="OrthoPersp">Change Parall/Persp</button>
    <button id="ShadingButton">Change Shading</button>


    <div>Traslation on X  <input id="slideX" type="range"
        min="-1" max="1" step="0.1" value="0" />
    </div>

    <div>Traslation on Y  <input id="slideY" type="range"
        min="-1" max="1" step="0.1" value="0" />
    </div>

    <div>Traslation on Z  <input id="slideZ" type="range"
        min="-1" max="1" step="0.1" value="0" />
    </div>

    <div>Scaling on X  <input id="ScalingX" type="range"
        min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0" />
    </div>
    <div>Scaling on Y <input id="ScalingY" type="range"
        min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0" />
    </div>
    <div>Scaling on Z  <input id="ScalingZ" type="range"
        min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0" />
    </div>

    <div>
        zNear Min<input id="zNearSlider" type="range" min="0.00" max="2.8" step="0.1" value="0.3">
            Max
            </div>

    <div>
        zFar Min<input id="zFarSlider" type="range" min="3" max="10" step="3.0" value="3">
            Max
            </div>







    <script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        precision mediump float;
        attribute  vec4 vPosition;
        attribute  vec4 vColor;

        varying vec4 fColor;

        //uniform vec3 theta;

        // Point 2 -> Move the matrices
        // Per spostare le matrici le abbiamo dovuto dichiarare nel file GLSL come uniform
        // le matrici rx ry e rz sono rispettivamente le matrici di rotazione sugli assi
        uniform mat4 rx;
        uniform mat4 ry;
        uniform mat4 rz;

        // Points 3 -> Traslation Matrix
        uniform mat4 traslation;
        // Points 3 -> Scaling Matrix
        uniform mat4 scaling;

        //Point 4 -> MV and P matrices
        uniform mat4 modelView;
        uniform mat4 projection;

        //Poinit 6 -> Light Source

        attribute vec4 vNormal;
        uniform vec4 ambientProduct, diffuseProduct, specularProduct;
        uniform vec4 lightPosition;
        uniform float shininess;
        varying vec3 N,L,E;
        uniform bool changeShading;

        void main()
        {
            // Compute the sines and cosines of theta for each of
            //   the three axes in one computation.
            //vec3 angles = radians( theta );
            //vec3 c = cos( angles );
            //vec3 s = sin( angles );

            // Remember: the matrices are column-major
            /*
             mat4 rx = mat4( 1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,
             0.0,  c.x,  s.x, 0.0,
             0.0, -s.x,  c.x, 0.0,
             0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );

             mat4 ry = mat4( c.y, 0.0, -s.y, 0.0,
             0.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0,
             s.y, 0.0,  c.y, 0.0,
             0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );


             mat4 rz = mat4( c.z, s.z, 0.0, 0.0,
             -s.z,  c.z, 0.0, 0.0,
             0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
             0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
             */

            //fColor = vColor;
            // ORDINE : scaling -> rotazione -> traslation

            //gl_Position = projection*modelView*scaling *rz * ry * rx * traslation *vPosition ;
            //gl_Position.z = -gl_Position.z;

            //Point 6
            vec3 pos = -(modelView * vPosition).xyz;
            if(changeShading) {
                vec3 light = lightPosition.xyz;
                vec3 L = normalize( light - pos );
                vec3 E = normalize( -pos );
                vec3 H = normalize( L + E );
                vec3 N = normalize( (modelView*vNormal).xyz);

                vec4 ambient = ambientProduct;

                float Kd = max( dot(L, N), 0.0 );
                vec4 diffuse = Kd*diffuseProduct;

                float Ks = pow( max(dot(N, H), 0.0), shininess );
                vec4 specular = Ks * specularProduct;

                if( dot(L, N) < 0.0 ) {
                    specular = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                }

                fColor = ambient + diffuse + specular;
                fColor.a = 1.0;


                gl_Position = projection*modelView*scaling *rz * ry * rx * traslation *vPosition ;
                gl_Position.z = -gl_Position.z;
            }
            else {
                vec3 light = lightPosition.xyz;
                vec3 L = normalize( light - pos );
                vec3 E = normalize( -pos );
                vec3 H = normalize( L + E );
                vec3 N = normalize( (modelView*vNormal).xyz);
                gl_Position = projection*modelView*scaling *rz * ry * rx * traslation *vPosition ;
                gl_Position.z = -gl_Position.z;
            }



            // *******************

        }
    </script>

    <script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

        precision mediump float;
        varying  vec4 vPosition;
        varying  vec4 vColor;

        varying vec4 fColor;
        uniform mat4 rx;
        uniform mat4 ry;
        uniform mat4 rz;


        uniform mat4 traslation;

        uniform mat4 scaling;


        uniform mat4 modelView;
        uniform mat4 projection;



        varying vec4 vNormal;
        uniform vec4 ambientProduct, diffuseProduct, specularProduct;
        uniform vec4 lightPosition;
        uniform float shininess;
        varying vec3 N,L,E;
        uniform bool changeShading;

        void main()
        {
            if(changeShading) {gl_FragColor = fColor;}
            else {vec4 fColor;
                vec3 H = normalize( L + E );
                vec4 ambient = ambientProduct;
                float Kd = max( dot(L, N), 0.0 );
                vec4 diffuse = Kd*diffuseProduct;
                float Ks = pow( max(dot(N, H), 0.0), shininess );
                vec4 specular = Ks * specularProduct;
                if( dot(L, N) < 0.0 ) specular = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                fColor = ambient + diffuse +specular;
                fColor.a = 1.0;
                gl_FragColor = fColor;}

        }
    </script>




    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/initShaders.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/MV.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Homework1.js"></script>



    <body>
        <canvas id="gl-canvas" width="1024" height="1024">
            Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question is off topic for SO because it doesn't provide a **minimal, complete, verifiable, example**. Your example is neither minimal, nor complete, and so not verifiable. Please look into [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable, example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349789/how-do-i-create-a-minimal-complete-verifiable-example) and given this is a JavaScript question please look into [how to create a working snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). This will make your question more useful to others.

Comment: @gman I'm really sorry if it is not an appropriate question , when you answered me I noticed that there was no uploading of the images that now I posted. I decided to post all of my code because I don't know where the problem is , and I tried to post the snippet but I'm looking for a solution of a common error in snipping uploading. Meanwhile I hope the images could explain better my problem.

Comment: If you read the links I posted you should be able to update your code so it runs in a snippet which would make your question acceptable. It would really help with this and future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the vertex shader are declared the varying (output) variables `N`, `L`, `E`. But they are never set, because there are identically named local variables which are set.
This causes that the values of the varying (input) variables `N`, `L`, `E` in the fragment shader are always (0, 0, 0).

The issue can be fixed by removing the declaration of the local variables and setting the varying outputs:

```
L = normalize( light - pos );
E = normalize( -pos );
N = normalize( (modelView*vNormal).xyz);
```